# Closing the panels in container UIView with DropDownMenu Swift 4 Constraint

Tags: ios, swift

The issue stated that it has something to do with the hierarchy, I'm new to swift 4 and google maps.

Issue on the  `dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true` when closing the panel from the container.

```
override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    self.superview?.addSubview(dropView)
    self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: dropView)
    dropView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true // Having issue here for bottom anchor when closing the UIViewController
    dropView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    dropView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    height = dropView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
}
```

This is the code where container is closing.

```
isHidden = !isHidden
        animateStatusBar()
        hideGrayCoverView()

        animateCenterPanelYPosition(targetPosition: 0) { (finished) in
            if finished {
                self.currentState = .collapsed
                if let mapSettings = self.mapFilterSettingsVC {
                    mapSettings.view.removeFromSuperview()
                    mapSettings.removeFromParentViewController()
                }
                self.mapFilterSettingsVC = nil
            }
        }
```

Error Stacks

> Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
>   The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.
>   2018-07-24 10:18:30.890527+0800 Pegasus[3510:65686] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
>   2018-07-24 10:18:30.890651+0800 Pegasus[3510:65686] TIC Read Status [3:0x0]: 1:57
>   2018-07-24 10:18:31.017810+0800 Pegasus[3510:65443] Google Maps SDK for iOS and Google Places API for iOS version: 2.7.30514.0
>   2018-07-24 10:18:34.211751+0800 Pegasus[3510:65443] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors  and  because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fixed it by removing the `mapSettings.removeFromParentViewController()`

I think it make sense to me because you are trying to remove the whole `UIViewController` when you are closing it from the container view (another `UIViewController` that handles all the controller from it).